# Posts on Tumblr page not working

Tags: html, post, blogs, tumblr

I'm working on a Tumblr theme and only some of the post types are showing up. If it makes a difference, the ones that work (titles, text posts, and photosets) are the first things written in my code and then the rest doesn't show up.

Here's what the HTML for my posts looks like:

```
{block:Posts}

<div class="posts">

    {block:Title}<div class="titles">{Title}</div>{/block:Title}

    {block:Text}{Body}{/block:Text}

    {block:Photo}
        {LinkOpenTag}
            <a href="{permalink}"><img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" width="100%" /></a>
        {LinkCloseTag}
        <br>{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
    {/block:Photo}

    {block:Panorama}
        {LinkOpenTag}
            <a href="{permalink}"><img src="{PhotoURL-Panorama}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/></a>
        {LinkCloseTag}
        <br>{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
    {/block:Panorama}

    {block:Photoset}
        {Photoset-400}
        <br>{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
    {/block:Photoset}

    {block:Quote}
        <div class="quotes">{Quote}</div>
        {block:Source}-{Source}{/block:Quote}
    {/block:Quote}

    {block:Video}
        {Video-500}
        <br>{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
    {/block:Video}

    {block:Link}
        <div style="padding:5px;">
        <div class="links"><a href="{URL}" {Target}>{Name}</a></div>
        <br>{block:Description}{Description}{/block:Description}
        </div>
    {/block:Link}

    {block:Chat}
        {block:Label}<strong>{Label}</strong>{/block:Label}:
        {block:Lines}{Line}{/block:Lines}
    {/block:Chat}

    {block:AudioPlayer}
        {AudioPlayerBlack}
        <br>{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
    {/block:AudioPlayer}

    {block:Answer}
        {Asker}
        <div class="asks">{Question}</div>

        {Answerer}
        <div class="asks">{Answer}</div>
    {/block:Answer}

{/block:Post}
```

If anyone knows why any of these aren't working, I really appreciate the help.

EDIT:
I've taken down this blog, but I'm leaving the question up in case anyone recognizes this problem and know how to help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you post the entire `{block:Posts}` logic.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the closing theme operator `{/block:Post}` is incorrect. It should be `{/block:Posts}`. Below is a revision, with comments:

```
{block:Posts}
<div class="posts">

    {block:Text}
    <!-- Title only applies to text posts -->
    {block:Title}
    <div class="titles">{Title}</div>
    {/block:Title}
    {Body}
    {/block:Text}

    {block:Photo}
    {LinkOpenTag}
    <a href="{permalink}"><img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" width="100%" /></a>
    {LinkCloseTag}
    <br>{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
    {/block:Photo}

    {block:Panorama}
    {LinkOpenTag}
    <a href="{permalink}"><img src="{PhotoURL-Panorama}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/></a>
    {LinkCloseTag}
    <br>{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
    {/block:Panorama}

    {block:Photoset}
    {Photoset-400}
    <br>{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
    {/block:Photoset}

    {block:Quote}
    <div class="quotes">{Quote}</div>
    {block:Source}-{Source}{/block:Quote}
    {/block:Quote}

    {block:Video}
    {Video-500}
    <br>{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
    {/block:Video}

    {block:Link}
    <div style="padding:5px;">
    <div class="links"><a href="{URL}" {Target}>{Name}</a></div>
    <br>{block:Description}{Description}{/block:Description}
    </div>
    {/block:Link}

    {block:Chat}
    {block:Label}<strong>{Label}</strong>{/block:Label}:
    {block:Lines}{Line}{/block:Lines}
    {/block:Chat}

    <!-- Audio Embed / Player is specific to the audio post -->
    {block:Audio}
    {block:AudioEmbed}
    <!-- Use the newest Tumblr Audio Player -->
    {AudioEmbed-400}
    {/block:AudioEmbed}
    <br>{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
    {/block:Audio}

    {block:Answer}
    {Asker}
    <div class="asks">{Question}</div>

    {Answerer}
    <div class="asks">{Answer}</div>
    {/block:Answer}

{/block:Posts}
</div>
```

Comment: This didn't seem to make a difference. I'm probably doing something else wrong. Thanks for trying!

Comment: @user3399933 if you can add a url / example it maybe more helpful.